# django-table2 - Change background color for entire row depending on the value of specific column

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have been trying to highlight an entire row of a table with django-table2 package.

I managed to change font color of one record doing the below:

```
def render_MyValue(self, value, column, record):
   if record['Warning']:
       column.attrs = {'td': {'style': 'color:darkorange;'}}
   else:
       column.attrs = {'td': {'style': 'color:black;'}}
   return value
```

Find below my table class:

```
class DetailedReportTable(tables.Table):
    MyValue = tables.Column(orderable=False, verbose_name='Value')
    ...
    Warning = tables.Column(orderable=False, visible=False)
```

The problem is I cannot find how to set the background of the row in orange if Warning is True.

Following the doc [here](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html#row-attributes) I tried also the below:

```
class DetailedReportTable(tables.Table):
    ...

    class Meta:
        row_attrs = { "bg-color": lambda record: "#8B0000" if record['Warning'] else "#000000" }
```

But this is doing nothing...

How can you change background color for a row using django-table2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've tried is close, but you're just setting an attribute of "bg-color" on the row html element - that attribute doesn't exist. Instead, you want to set either a class, which you can style in CSS, or directly set a style attribute. Here's the second option:

```py
class DetailedReportTable(tables.Table):
    ...

    class Meta:
        row_attrs = { "style": lambda record: "background-color: #8B0000;" if record['Warning'] else "background-color: #000000;" }
```

Comment: Nice. This is working perfectly fine. Thank you for explaining why it was not working!